# backbone.js: the template can't recognize the model

Tags: templates, view, model, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="action-template-item">
    <span data-layer="<%= target%>" data-uuid="<%= uuid%>">delete</span>
</script>
```

I render the template in a view

```
    window.ActionView = Backbone.View.extend({
          template: $("#action-template-item").html(),
          initialize: function () {
                this.render();
          },
          render: function () {
              var tmpl = _.template(this.template);
              console.log(this.model);//model have "target"
              this.$el.html(tmpl(this.model));
              return this;
          }

    });
```

the template have only two property from model data,

before it render, I use console to check if the model have `target` value, the answer is positive,just like the comment above,

my model data is just like:

```
{
   target: "xxx-xxx-xxx",
   uuid: "xxx-xxx-xx"
}
```

but the firebug tell me `"target is not defined"`

What happened?What's wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your models probably look something like this:

```
var M = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var m = new M({
   target: "xxx-xxx-xxx",
   uuid: "xxx-xxx-xx"
});
```

Demo (open the console and you'll see your error): http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/Rnd6k/

So when you say

```
//model have "target"
```

you probably mean that `this.model.attributes.target` exists. Backbone model attributes and JavaScript object properties are not the same thing, the Underscore templates will be looking for object properties, they don't know anything about Backbone model attributes.

The usual approach is to serialize your model using [`toJSON`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-toJSON) when you want to render a view:

```
render: function () {
    var tmpl = _.template(this.template);
    this.$el.html(tmpl(this.model.toJSON()));
    return this;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/Rnd6k/

Comment: In fact, the `this.model` passed in is already one of the the model's attributes property,it has no `toJSON` method,also I think the `this.model.attributes` is aleady object type.You mean I need to convert the object type to a json type?

Comment: Now I have use a jquery json pulgin, use $.toJSON method to convert the object to a json datatype, but it still can not work,tell me the `target is not defined`

Comment: I have konw what'wrong with my code.it's a array item!node a object type!However thank you very much